# Creating a Quasar Data Table with JSON Data Array

Tags: json, quasar-framework

I am trying to use the JSON array to create a quasar table but I am not able to link the array data with the table data.

I have stored the data from my database into an array called "**scanResults**" and the result is as shown:

`console.log(scanResults);`

[Results of scanResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Hrg.png)

Among the three arrays (Items, Count, and ScannedCount), I only want the data from **Items**. Is there a way I could put the data from **scanResults** into **tableData** under data() in the  section such that I will be able to display the data into the quasar table?

```
tableData: [
 { 
   name: 'xxx',
   frequency: 'xxx',
   prescription: 'xxx',
   time: 'xxx'
 }
]
```

```
<q-table
  title="Reminders"
  no-data-label="You do not have any reminders yet!"
  align="center"
  :columns="columns"
  :data="tableData"
  row-key="name"
  selection="single"
  :selected.sync="selected"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your scanResults correctly, you can set

```
tableData = scanResults.0[1]
```

to put the contents of the second place (the data) of the first array ("0") into tableData.

Did you define the columns array? The bindings must include both arrays so that QTable knows which data to put in which column.  See the script tab of the "basic" section at https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table .